# Jupyter Installation Environment

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ubuntu-16.04

How can I check/know where was jupyter installed? On virtual environment/conda/OS?

> Linux/Ubuntu 16

In Terminal I get:

```
jupyter --version:

- jupyter core     : 4.6.1
- jupyter-notebook : 6.0.3
- qtconsole        : not installed
- ipython          : 7.11.1
- ipykernel        : 5.1.3
- jupyter client   : 5.3.4
- jupyter lab      : not installed
- nbconvert        : 5.6.1
- ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
- nbformat         : 5.0.4
- traitlets        : 4.3.3
```

Comment: We're up to Ubuntu 20.10 now.  Perhaps you should consider upgrading that.

Comment: You right about Ubuntu 20.04, but my problem is different.
It's my old laptop, and I'm trying to understand exactly where I installed Jupyter in the past.

Comment: How about `which -a jupyter` ?

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The suggested:

```
which jupyter -a
```

will not give you any useful info if you are running pyenv or another environment manager that uses shims. Instead, you may want to use:

```
jupyter --paths
```

and look under config and data - one of the paths is the install location; this may be also more useful if you want to really understand where jupyter loads the configuration from.

Comment: It helps. Thank you